# How to join win 8.1 to WSUS server 2012

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2012, wsus, windows-8.1

i have a wsus server on win server 2012 and over 30 win 8.1 clients.i need to know how to configure clients to get updates from local server.anyone can help?

note: all my network are in local domain that managed with active directory

Answer (score 4):

Group policy that points them to the WSUS server.

Microsoft has detailed information (oh my, 10 seconds on google, you know):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720539(ws.10).aspx

The relevant group policy settings are under

Computer Configuration, expand Administrative Templates, expand Windows Components, and then click Windows Update.

and there you then set the URL of the WSUS server (including port number).